# TLS handshake works in Editor but not on HoloLens

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-blob-storage, hololens

In our HoloLens project we have a feature that runs with Azure blob-storage.

The goal of this feature is to upload/download files from Azure.

Working with Unity `2020.3.19` (UWP-platform) and MRTK 2.7 the feature is running smoothly.

Updating to Unity `2020.3.25` the feature still works in Editor, but on HoloLens there the following error pops up:

`TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: 4294950016`

Apparently this is related to some certification issue, does anybody have the same experience or found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from an Unity internal issue.

[Here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/tlsexception-handshake-failed-error-when-uwp-build-configuration-is-set-to-release?_ga=2.150892278.194877348.1642332040-99495130.1587982187) is the link to the Unity issue-tracker

The only way to prevent this issue for now is to downgrade the Unity version.